# Regular Expression to select name from following code

Tags: java, regex

```
alt="Abdul Aziz" width="75" height="75" class="thumb-border"></td>
```

I want to select "Abdul Aziz" from the html above. How should I do this? It must be generic as I have to select many names from similar looking HTML.

Comment: What platform? What language? Do you realize that regex tends to be a [poor choice for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583)?

Comment: It's not always wise to use regex on HTML. There are nice parsing libraries for almost all platform, might give that a try.

Comment: Could you please mention the whole tag ? if you are using jQuery or YUI you could use selector.

Comment: Client-side Javascript is _especially_ well equipped to getting an attribute of an existing element. If you have jQuery, you can do it just as easily _and_ with a shorter syntax than with vanilla.js

Comment: Well actually it was an assignment of my subject Java Development
I was forced to do this with RE using java by Professor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alt="[\w\s]+"
```

Will select the whole statement, and then you can remove the alt and quotes with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what language you are using, but here's a pattern that would start to get you there.  Beware that parsing HTML with regexes has all sorts of downsides.

```
"/alt=\"(.*?)\".*?>/"
```

This will retrieve the stuff between alt="" into the first capture group.

Comment: Not sure "beware that ..." cuts it.

Comment: Really depends on how much/what parsing.  Very targeted, very limited use of regexes for this purpose may be the most practical in some scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript would be more consistent:

```
//You can get elements by tag :
els = document.getElementsByTag('td');

// or you can get elements by class name :
els = document.getElementsByClassName('thumb-border');
```

and then iterate through your elements and read the alt attribute.

or if using jQuery you can use selector:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/